# Azure AD / Microsoft Graph Tokens - What to use for a multi-client app

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid, microsoft-graph-api

I need to be able to monitor a user's Hotmail or Outlook account in the offline mode via a backend.  But the user can sign up and authorize the account access either from a web app e.g. Laravel or Lumen or from a Cordova mobile app or another SPA interface such as Angular.   Basically, the app is configured on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com for an implicit flow.

Since the app requires a backend offline processing lets say few times a day - I will need a refresh token to renew the access_token.  There are two ways to get consent from the Azure AD.

1. authorize = id_token + token  (But the limitation is that id_token is only client specific).  This approach is more suitable for fetching the emails when client is running and user is online.
2. authorize = code and then generate access_token and refresh_token.

Question - would option 2 work for both hotmail/outlook.com and O365?  If the access and refresh tokens are generated by the client - would they work for both online and offline access of a user's account and email.

Comment: The option2 is not implicit grant flow, it's code grant flow. Though you can get refresh token with this flow,but you also need user to sign in first. After getting a refresh token ,you can use it. It works for both MSA and AAD Account.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT  - What do you mean by need user to sign in first?  Based on your comment it would be - user signs up from the mobile app.  The code is generated.  Code is used to get access and refresh tokens.  Refresh token is stored on the server side e.g. Laravel.  The refresh token can then be used to make the silent call by the Laravel server to get a new access token and use it for getting user's email from Hotmail and O365.  On the client side access token is stored in the local storage and if expired can be refreshed by getting the refresh token from the server / laravel.  Correct?

Comment: If the user doesn't  send a sign out request, the browswer won't clear the cookie which contains the token information. I don't know whether your user would sign-out if the user gets offline. If he/she needs to sign out, the cookie will be cleared . And he/she needs to sign in again if the user wants to use the application.

Comment: Yes - I understand that if the user logs out they will have to log back in.  But not reauthorize since they have authorized the app already. For the cordova app there won't be a cookie.  Instead, access token can be read from the user's account.  My main concerns was being able to refresh with the same fresh token on the client and server and being able to access both Hotmail and O365.  Looks like we are good from that perspective.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Um.. Do you meant that you want to use one refresh token to get two access token for two user account?

Comment: No, one refresh token for the same user but use it both on a SPA front end e.g. angular or Cordova app while the user is online.  And then use the same refresh token to get an access token when a user is not using the application but instead for the system to access user's account to get the relevant information.

Comment: I see. Of course you can . The refresh token is actually to do the job that gets new access token without UI,it can replace the code.But how do you get the refresh token to your backend server ? Though I'm not aware of cordova app... The refresh token should only be send to the client from AAD ednpoint.

Comment: Thank you.  That is all I needed to know.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. But if you want to receieve a refresh token in token response, your app must request and be granted the `offline_acesss scope`.

> The [`offline_access` scope](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#OfflineAccess) gives your app access to resources on behalf
>   of the user for an extended time. On the work account consent page,
>   this scope appears as the "Access your data anytime" permission. On
>   the personal Microsoft account consent page, it appears as the "Access
>   your info anytime" permission. When a user approves the `offline_access`
>   scope, your app can receive refresh tokens from the v2.0 token
>   endpoint. Refresh tokens are long-lived. Your app can get new access
>   tokens as older ones expire.

**REQUEST EXAMPLE:**

// Line breaks for legibility only

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&state=12345
```

Actually, if you use code grant flow to sign in AAD, you will see this Page:

[image]

If you click Yes, you will consent `offline_access` scope.**NOTE: This works for both MSA and AAD Account.**

You can see more details about `offline_access` sope in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#offlineaccess).